# How to return searched result to textbox by clicking on listbox row item

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to read data from a database to display in a listbox.

I have textboxs and comboboxs: txtIndex, txtEventID, cmbServer, cmbCompany, txtMessage...

When I click on "Show list" button, all data from DATA sheet will be read and populated in listbox. After clicking on listbox row item, all related information will be displayed in corresponding textboxs and comboboxs **for this case**.

I use FindAll function to implement search engine and searched result seems to be ok.

**Problem is**: When I click on Searched result in listbox, data which is displayed in textboxs and comboboxs is not correct.

It follows to list index, not what I want.

This is my code for displaying data (handled by UserForm1_Click())

```
Private Sub Listbox1_Click()

Dim strAddress As String
Dim idx As Long

'    idx = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1

For idx = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
    If ListBox1.Selected(idx) = True Then
        strAddress = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1

        UserForm1.txIndex.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("A" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtEventID.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("B" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtSource.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.cmbServer.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("D" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtMessage.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("E" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.cmbStatus.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("F" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtDate.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("G" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtDate.Text = VBA.Format(txtDate, "yyyy.mm.dd")

        UserForm1.txtIssueNo.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("H" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.cmbCompany.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("I" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtErrorType.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("J" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.cmbPriority.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("K" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtComment.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("L" & strAddress).Value
        UserForm1.txtName.Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("M" & strAddress).Value

        GoTo EndLoop
'        UserForm1.Show
    End If
Next idx

EndLoop:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Label25.Caption = "You're looking for event id:  " & txtEventID.Text

End Sub
```

The result is not correct. I want to display exactly related data to selected items in textboxs & comboboxs, but when I select searched result (displayed in first row), Useform showed 1 row data in sheet, not searched result.

Problem is shown in attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? The first row of your DATA sheet has the values "Index", "Event ID" and so on as column titles. Then the form is filled with these instead of the relevant row,  i.e. `strAddress` is always 1?

Comment: Hi arcadeprecinct, Yes, you're right. My first row shows the column title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, you shouldn't use a `UserForm1_Click()` event to display data, rather have a `SomeButton_Click` event do it

then you must have a `ListBox1_Click` event handle UserForm controls refreshing after selection of any `ListBox1` item
like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Listbox1_Click()
    Dim strAddress As Long
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet

    With Me
        If .ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Set dataSht = Sheets("DATA")
            strAddress = GetEventIDRow(.ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1), dataSht.Columns("B")) '<~~  GetEventIDRow returns "Data" sheet row corresponding to the selected EventID, which is got from the 2nd column of the selected ListBox row

            .txIndex.Value = dataSht.Range("A" & strAddress).Value
            .txtEventID.Value = dataSht.Range("B" & strAddress).Value
            .txtSource.Value = dataSht.Range("C" & strAddress).Value
            .cmbServer.Value = dataSht.Range("D" & strAddress).Value
            .txtMessage.Value = dataSht.Range("E" & strAddress).Value
            .cmbStatus.Value = dataSht.Range("F" & strAddress).Value
            .txtDate.Value = dataSht.Range("G" & strAddress).Value
            .txtDate.Text = VBA.Format(txtDate, "yyyy.mm.dd")

            .txtIssueNo.Value = dataSht.Range("H" & strAddress).Value
            .cmbCompany.Value = dataSht.Range("I" & strAddress).Value
            .txtErrorType.Value = dataSht.Range("J" & strAddress).Value
            .cmbPriority.Value = dataSht.Range("K" & strAddress).Value
            .txtComment.Value = dataSht.Range("L" & strAddress).Value
            .txtName.Value = dataSht.Range("M" & strAddress).Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function GetEventIDRow(EventID As Long, rng As Range) As Long
    GetEventIDRow = rng.Find(What:=EventID, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
End Function
```

please consider I'm nearly blind coding so you must adapt it to your actual data and control structure

Comment: Hi User3598756, thank you so much for your prompt reply. This's great comment and I highly appreciated it. I've already tested your code. It worked well when i tried to search record by some conditions in search box. However, in case of "Show list" button, "Add new" record, "Delete" & "Update", it seems that listbox_click () event doesn't work correctly. Selected item in listbox doesn't match with corresponding record in DATA sheet. I attached my full code here and could you please give me some hints else? Once again, thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: Thank you so much. I modified my code based on what you hinted. It worked perfectly. :)

Comment: I still have a wondering point in your hint. Could you please help me to make sense? It is: When I use: "strAddress = GetIndexRow(.ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0), dataSht.Columns("A")) ", to look up Index, Then showlist:

    With ListBox1
            '.ColumnHeads = True
            .List = Sheets("DATA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
            .ColumnCount = Sheets("DATA").Cells(2, 2).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    End With
When I click on first row (Column Header), error will come. how should I do in this case? I really appreciate your ideas, and thanks in advance!

Comment: not so clear to me what's your issue. you'd better put it in a new question adding the relevant code only (just a running excerpt of your handler sub and `GetIndexRow`). that would also in the path of SO rules...

Comment: I have already completed my program without any error else. It works well. Thank you so much for your help. Nice to talk with you. ^^